# Need help understanding Friedberg's proof of "Theorem 2.15"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is the theorem that he proves

[image]

In particular, I don't understand what he is doing in part (d)

[image]

Why does he assume that $T(x) = Cx$ from the linear transformation equation?

Comment: Please do not posts images; use MathJax. Images are not searchable, they interfere with screen readers that some users utilize, and they need not display well in all interfaces.

Comment: Presumably $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ is defined in Theorem 2.14?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a linear transformation $T : F^n \to F^m.$ Given that $\beta = \{v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ and $\gamma = \{w_1, \dots, w_m \}$ are the standard ordered bases of $F^n$ and $F^m,$ respectively, it follows that $T(v_1), \dots, T(v_n)$ can be written uniquely as linear combinations of $w_1, \dots, w_m.$ Explicitly, we have $$\begin{align*} T(v_1) &= a_{11} w_1 + a_{21} w_2 + \cdots + a_{m1} w_m \\ \\ T(v_2) &= a_{12} w_1 + a_{22} w_2 + \cdots + a_{m2} w_m  \\ \\  &\, \, \vdots \\ \\ T(v_n) &= a_{1n} w_1 + a_{2n} w_2 + \cdots + a_{mn} w_m\end{align*}$$ for some scalars $a_{ij}$ in $F.$ Consequently, we obtain a matrix $C = [a_{ij}]_{1 \leq i \leq m, \, 1 \leq j \leq n}$ such that $T(x) = Cx$ for any vector $x$ in $F^n.$ We can verify this by observing that if $x = v_j,$ then $$T(x) = T(v_j) = a_{1j} w_1 + a_{2j} w_2 + \cdots + a_{mj} w_j = \langle a_{1j}, a_{2j}, \dots, a_{mj} \rangle = Cv_j.$$ Recall that a linear transformation is uniquely determined by how it acts on a basis.